# Spring hangs on user authentication when database has a password

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

The problem is most evident when I'm testing my webapp with JUnit+Selenium. When pressing the submit button on the Login page, the amount of time it takes the test to move forward depends on whether my database has a password or not.

When the database has no password (user="root", password="") it's almost instantaneous, as it should be. When the database does have a password (say, user="root", password="randomSecurePassword") it takes upwards of a minute and a half. Still succeeds, in the end, but takes long enough that the web driver times out before it finishes.

I'm not terribly familiar with this technology, so I'm willing to provide any details that might be necessary for this that don't come to mind for me. For the time being, some details about the environment I'm trying to work in:

- The software stack involves Hibernate, Spring, and Maven (for building and testing). When I just build the project on the server, I can run all my tests with JUnit directly, and I don't have this problem. When I run the program as a Maven Build, and have it run all the tests, the problem does occur.
- The following statement is used to set the data source for Spring to authenticate users:

  ```
  dbManager.dataSource( dataSource ).passwordEncoder( passwordEncoder() )
          .usersByUsernameQuery( "select username,password,enabled from Users where username=?" )
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery( "select username,role from Users where username=?" );
  ```
- I'm very sure that the `dataSource` is being initialized correctly; none of the unit tests for the rest of the program, that use the same data source, experience any problems or delays in accessing the database through it.

Hopefully I've explained the problem well. Thanks in advance for any help.